# Checking the empty value of a an attribute

Tags: python, xml

I need to check to see if the intent value exists or not and if it doesn't exist, I'd like to have it assigned 'UNASSIGNED'

```
   for info in data:
        intent = info.getAttribute("intentref")
        
        if (intent) == None:
            intent = 'NOT_ASSIGNED'
          
        utterance = info.firstChild.nodeValue
```

But it's not working. any idea?

[image]

Left side - instead of blank, it should say 'UNASSIGNED'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

```
intent= info.get(intentref,'NOT_ASSIGNED')
```

not sure if it's the same for lxml but using "get" like this in other xml parsers allows you to set a default value if not found

Comment: Thanks, I think I wrote the wrong question. I edited the question. Basically, I'm looking to if 'intent' value is null and if it does, we need to give UNASSIGNED.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by the doing the following:

```
intent = info.getAttribute("intentref")

if (len(intent)) < 1:
    intent = 'NOT_ASSIGNED'
```